# updating and leaving some libs untouched

Tags: cocoapods

I have this Podfile

```
platform :ios
pod 'ShareKit'
pod'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'HockeySDK'
```

Now I want to add a new library, but leave the existing ones untouched. Is that possible without having to add the version number to the libraries, and how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the podfile with the existing libraries, along with the new library name
and execute `pod install`

For example adding AFNetworking

Update pod file as

```
platform :ios
pod 'ShareKit'
pod'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'HockeySDK'
pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'
```

Then call

```
pod install
```

To install the changes you have made to your Podfile, or to bootstrap your installation for a project which doesn't keep the Pods folder under version control, use:

```
$ pod install
```

Pod install **will not update your dependencies even if a new version is available**, to update them you can use:

```
$ pod update
```

Comment: Your completely right...   I was fooled by a software that did an update, why it claimed to do an install. Thanks!